# Wordpress Plugins Menu Position & Title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How would I go about moving the position of a wordpress plugin that is installed from the Wordpress Plugin Repository?  I want to do this in the functions.php file for learning purposes and because the theme will be utilizing the same plugins and I can set them with the names I want and the correct position.

What is the easiest way to change an installed plugins position and any menu titles?  I've changed some of the core installed menu titles but not an installed plugin.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your directory `Plugins > Your Plugin`. 
At very beginning, you'll see some comments.
You can set name, description etc there.

```
/*
Plugin Name: (Name of Plugin that will be seen on Installed Plugin section.)
Description: (Your Plugin description.)
 */
```